# Swipe Event : no access to the Component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Following the tutorial, I'm developping my fist app. In this app, I want to implements swipe for navigation.
But I'm facing an issue : I cannot access to my component object.

I'm using NativeScript + Angular.

```
constructor(
    private _router: Router
    , private _routeParams: RouteParams
    , private _signalListService: SignalListService
    , private _page : Page
) {
    console.log('ViewPageConstructor : ' + this);
    this.itemId = this._routeParams.get("id");

    this._page.on("swipe", function(args: gestures.SwipeGestureEventData) {
        console.log("Swipe Direction From event function: " + args.direction);
        console.log(args);  // [object Object]
        console.log(_page); // Page(148)
        console.log(this);  // undefined
        this.swipe(args); // Nothing happen ... no error ...
    });
}

swipe(args: gestures.SwipeGestureEventData) {
     console.log("Swipe Direction From event function: " + args.direction);
     this._router(...
}
```

I never get to the swipe function. There is non error in the command log ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure..  **this** inside your swipe event is not ***this*** from your constructor.
What you can do us to "cache" your constructor reference:

```
export class AppComponent  {

    constructor(private page: Page) {

        var that = this;

        this.page.on("swipe", function(args: gestures.SwipeGestureEventData) {
            console.log("Swipe Direction From event function: " + args.direction);

            that.onSwipe(); 
        })
    }

    public onSwipe() {
        console.log("onSwipe triggered");
    }
}
```